# How can i bind a button in listviewitem to a Command in ViewModel in Winrt

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I have a **NavigateToAccountsCommand**  RelayCommand property in the ViewModel. When I bind the same to a button on the page anywhere outside the ListView the command binding is working. However as soon as I move this to a ListView's DataTemplate its not working.

I have tried changing the binding from **NavigateToAccountsCommand** to **DataContext.NavigateToAccountsCommand** still not working.

Appreciate your help...

```
<Page
x:Class="FinancePRO.App.Views.AccountsView"
DataContext="{Binding AccountsViewModel, Source={StaticResource MainViewModelLocator}}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
      <!--**This one is working**-->
      <Button  Command="{Binding NavigateToAccountsCommand}" >

     <!--**This one is not working**-->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccounts}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}"/>
                      <Button  Command="{Binding NavigateToAccountsCommand}">
                                </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are inside the `DataTemplate` of the `ListView`, your data context is the current item of the ListView's `ItemsSource`. As there is nothing called "`NavigateToAccountsCommand`" property within your `AllAcounts`' each individual element, binding isn't working.

To fix that, you will need to reference something from the outside of `DataTemplate`; following should work. It changes the binding to reference the root Grid's `DataContext` which should have the property `NavigateToAccountsCommand` accessible. To reference the grid, you have to add Name attribute, and then use `ElementName` binding.

```
    <Grid Name="Root">
          <!--**This one is working**-->
          <Button  Command="{Binding NavigateToAccountsCommand}" >

         <!--**This one is not working**-->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccounts}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}"/>
                          <Button  Command"{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.NavigateToAccountsCommand}">
                                    </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks loopedcode, for the prompt response. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
<Button x:Name="cmdTabItemCloseButton" 
                                Style="{StaticResource TabItemCloseButtonStyle}"
                                Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, 
                Path=DataContext.NavigateToAccountsCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Dhaval. This works in a normal WPF app, however doesnt work in a WInRT app. thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem (Win RT) which I solved by just using:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```

and then in the Page class:

```
    private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //e is the object being clicked
    }
```