# Force ListView to refresh or Invalidate in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` with `ItemTemplate`. I want to bind one control background in `ItemTemplate` to 2 properties, one of properties is in ItemsSource and onother one is in my page. since `UWP` has no `multibinding` support, I bind it to one property in ItemSource and for another property in my page I want to handle it in my code behind.

```
<ListView >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           x:Name="myborder"
                           Padding="5,0,5,0"
                           Background="{Binding myProperty, Converter={StaticResource convertPropertyToBgColor },ConverterParameter=border}">
                                <StackPanel Padding="0,10,10,10"
                                            Background="{Binding myProperty, Converter={StaticResource convertPropertyToBgColor},ConverterParameter=stack}">
                                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                                </StackPanel>
                  </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

in the `convertPropertyToBgColor` I get the brush from Resources.

and in code behind when my second desired property is changed I Change My resources. so the brush I have used from resources get changed and because of that I want to call that converter again to refresh Background, I called `updateLayout` but it doesn't refresh my ListView and it doesn't call myConvereter again. How can I force ListView to recreate or refresh Items that it has made?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged), then once you change the property, usually in its *setter* you also call *OnPropertyChanged* event which will update your UI. There are plenty examples of that, [here is one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/).

The other way, may be to call `Bindings.Update()`, but normally you probably should use the method above.

---

To make my comments clearer - something like this is possible:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="myList" Width="200">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       x:Name="myborder"
                       Padding="5,0,5,0"
                       Background="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, ElementName=myList}">
                    <StackPanel Padding="0,10,10,10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <x:String>Element 1</x:String>
        <x:String>Element 2</x:String>
        <x:String>Element 3</x:String>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Change" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private SolidColorBrush myPropety = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    public SolidColorBrush MyProperty
    {
        get { return myPropety; }
        set { myPropety = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(MyProperty)); }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => MyProperty = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

Comment: My itemsSource is a independent class that I used in different Pages . you mean I should go to that class and change it? that property is in this page, so that class doesn't understand it has changed

Comment: @Maryam Implement in that class *INotifyPropertyChanged*, then define method for example: `void RaiseProperty(string property) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));` and call that in property's setter at the end `RaiseProperty(nameof(property));`. This should do the job.

Comment: @Maryam Another question `myProperty` is in Page? Not in class? Then it won't work as *DataContext* is different. You can change that, probably for example by using as a *Source*, page's *DataContext*. However I'm not sure if I won't put another property in the class.

Comment: as i said in question that property changes my resources in whole app so I just want that converter get called again to get the new color, it doesn't need to be as part of dataContext. I just want that ListView refresh it's UI

Comment: If you use Binging, then you have a DataContext - where it looks for the property. If you want to change the property and see the cahnge, then this DataContext should implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*. As for your code, your datacontext is an element's class in your itemssource. You can change that for [example like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19646872/2681948) - to datacontext of element in page. Another way may be to declare a resource in app's `<Resources>` and use that, however that class used for resource should also implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*.

Comment: If you want to make it 'dirty way', then make a property from your ItemsSource* and bind it in *ListView*: `<ListView ItemsSource={x:Bind myItems, Mode=OneWay}>`. Then every time you want refresh/change the collection call `Bindings.Update()`. A step better would be to (again) implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* on page and invoke *PropertyChanged* once you need to refresh itemssource. However look that in the above comment's method, refreshed is only what is needed, items are not created again and so on - this is much better.

Comment: as I said I have 2 properties .my listview dataContext  is its itemSource. I bind it to one of itemSource's properties  it works fine. when I change some  property in the page not in ItemsSource, I want the listview refresh again. because in the converter I get the color from myresource SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["Red"]) that is changed

Comment: @Maryam I'm not sure if we understand each other, therefore to show what I've on my mind see the edit in the answer - it's a complete sample app. Give it a try and see if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes I think we don't understand each other maybe because my question is not complete. MyProperty is one of attributes in ItemsSource class and I used Converter that according to that property I pick a color. so for each row the color is different according to that property of that rowItem. it works fine. but the problem is when I change another property in class not in Items, so I want that converter again get called again

Comment: @Maryam The converter will be called once you invoke *RaiseProperty* on suitable item -> it will invoke the getter and then converter. You cannot just like that call converter. I must say that I'm lost in this what you try to achieve, if possible please build a sample app that will reproduce the issue.